# DAX formula to COUNT() or DISCTINTCOUNT() based on condition?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, formula, dax

I want to include a new measure using a DAX formula in a Pivot Table. I have the following DAX formula to count unique values in Column1

```
= DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Column1])
```

How can I COUNT() values equal to "XYZ" and DISTINCTCOUNT() values different than "XYZ". I've tried something like this but is not working.

```
=IF(Table1[Column1] <> "XYZ",
     DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Column1]),
     COUNT(Table1[Column1])
```

**Sample Input**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| Id | Column1 | Column2 |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | ABC     | A       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | DEF     | A       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | GHI     | B       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | ABC     | A       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | IIU     | XYZ     |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | HYW     | A       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | ABC     | A       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | ABC     | B       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | WQW     | XYZ     |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | ABC     | A       |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | RTT     | XYZ     |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | PPO     | XYZ     |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**Output I'm looking for:**

```
+----+---+---+-----+
| ID | A | B | XYZ |
+----+---+---+-----+
| 1  | 3 | 2 | 4   |
+----+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: A measure can only return one final number. Which output value do you want to return?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Hi Alexis. I've updated in my original post with a more appropiated sample input and output I'm looking for. I have a table with several IDs (in this sample I show only ID=1). I'd like to count DISTINT for which Column2="A", DISTICNTCOUTN for which Column2="B" and COUNT values for which Column2 = "XYZ". I hope make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output table is helpful.

I think you want something like this:

```
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Column2] ) = "XYZ",
    COUNT ( Table1[Column2] ),
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Column1] )
)
```

If you only have one value in your filter context and that value is `"XYZ"` then you count the occurrences of `"XYZ"`. Otherwise, count the number of distinct `Column1` values.

---

If working with old versions that don't support `SELECTEDVALUE` try this:

```
count =
IF (
    IF ( HASONEVALUE ( Table1[Column2] ), VALUES ( Table1[Column2] ) ) = "XYZ",
    COUNT ( Table1[Column2] ),
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Column1] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Alexis. I've tried in DAX studio, Excel 2016. First I put `DEFINE`, then `MEASURE Table1[myMeasure]= your code` then I use `EVALUATE ROW("Test", Table1[myMeasure])` and I get error `Failed to resolve name SELECTEDVALUE. It is not a valid table, variable or function name`

Comment: Ah, you must be using an older version. `SELECTEDVALUE` is a shortcut for `IF(HASONEVALUE(<Column>), VALUES(<Column>))`.

Comment: Excellent Alexis. Now it works on DAX Studio and with Excel Pivot Table measure. I got another error with COUNT() that seems to work only with numeric values and I found that using COUNTA() fixes the issue. I have a similar situation with another table. I'll try to see If I can get the output modifying your solution, if not I'll open a new question. Thanks